# How to count how many times storyboard animation looped?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation

I have code like this

```
    <Storyboard x:Key="AdvMarquee" Completed="Storyboard_Completed">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)" From="-25"    To="0"      BeginTime="0:00:00" Duration="0:00:01" />
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)" From="0"      To="25"     BeginTime="0:00:03" Duration="0:00:01" />
    </Storyboard>
    <Style x:Key="AnimationImageStyle" TargetType="StackPanel">
        <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="200" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource AdvMarquee}"/>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

And Applied this Animation style with this code

```
    <Canvas x:Name="Advertise" Background="{x:Null}" Margin="10,0,0,0" >
        <StackPanel Style="{StaticResource AnimationImageStyle}">
            <Button Click="Advertise_Click" Style="{StaticResource AdvertisementBtnStyle}">
                <TextBlock Name="AdvText" Text="This is Animated Text" Padding="10, 0, 10, 0"/>
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Canvas>
```

I've tried to use Completed Event on Storyboard to calculate how many times Storyboard animation executed.

Before this, I tried to add RepeatBehavior="Forever" on Storyboard but it just loop forever and didn't run completed event.

and now, when I remove RepeatBehavior="Forever", it complete it's progress, count up, but it doesn't run again.

how can I solve this problem?

still have no idea cuz I'm really new to work with xaml wpfform.

My Storyboard_Completed is just like this.

```
int count = 0;
private void Storyboard_Completed( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    count++;
}
```

Comment: In case you want to repeat the Storyboard for a certain number of counts, set e.g. `RepeatBehavior="10x"`. As a note, the middle animation `From="0" To="0"` is useless.

Comment: @Clemens : Got it. I've removed middle animation which actually doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put event handler for `CurrentStateInvalidated` for the last animation and you will have the possibility to get current iteration:

```
<DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)" From="0"      To="25"     BeginTime="0:00:03" Duration="0:00:01" CurrentStateInvalidated="DoubleAnimation_CurrentStateInvalidated"/>

int cnt=0;    
private void DoubleAnimation_CurrentStateInvalidated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ac = sender as AnimationClock;
    cnt = (ac.Parent as ClockGroup).CurrentIteration;
}
```

`Storyboard_Completed` you will not need.

Comment: need to repeat infinitely this animation. so if it limit the loop, it is not for my question.

Comment: changed answer works for both finite and infinite cases